# How can I convert `curl --data=@filename` to Python requests?

Tags: python, curl, python-requests

I'm calling `curl` from a Perl script to POST a file:

```perl
my $cookie = 'Cookie: _appwebSessionId_=' . $sessionid;
my $reply  = `curl -s
                   -H "Content-type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
                   -H "$cookie"
                   --data \@portports.txt
                   http://$ipaddr/remote_api.esp`;
```

I want to use the Python [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/) module instead. I've tried the following Python code:

```py
files = {'file': ('portports.txt', open('portports.txt', 'rb'))}
headers = {
    'Content-type' : 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    'Cookie' : '_appwebSessionId_=%s' % sessionid
}

r = requests.post('http://%s/remote_api.esp' % ip, headers=headers, files=files)    
print(r.text)
```

But I always get the response "ERROR no data found in request." How can I fix this?

Comment: Why does this question have a Perl tag?

Comment: @Borodin The curl snippet came from a perl script

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `files` parameter encodes your file as a multipart message, which is not what you want. Use the `data` parameter instead:

```
import requests

url = 'http://www.example.com/'
headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
cookies = {'_appwebSessionId_': '1234'}

with open('foo', 'rb') as file:
    response = requests.post(url, headers=headers, data=file, cookies=cookies)
    print(response.text)
```

This generates a request like:

```
POST / HTTP/1.1
Connection: keep-alive
Accept: */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Host: www.example.com
User-Agent: python-requests/2.13.0
Content-Length: 15
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Cookie: _appwebSessionId_=1234

content of foo
```

Note that in both this version and in your original `curl` command, the file must already be URL encoded.

Comment: This worked. Thank you! I can't accept it as the right answer as I don't have enough rep on this site.

Comment: @AlexN Great, glad it worked for you. You can accept answers at any rep level, you just can't upvote until 15. See the [privileges page](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges).

Answer (score -1):

First UTF-8 decode your URL.

Put headers and files in a JSON object, lesse all_data.

Now your code should look like this.

```python
all_data = {
    {
        'file': ('portports.txt', open('portports.txt', 'rb'))
    },
    {
        'Content-type' : 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
        'Cookie' : '_appwebSessionId_=%s' % sessionid
    }
}


all_data = json.dumps(all_data)
requests.post(url, data = all_data)
```

Comment: The brackets aren't right, should there be an extra bracket at the start:
    all_data = {{ file...

if so then it gives an error saying unhashable type dict

Comment: @Borodin With your edit to the code it still says "unhashable type: dict"

Comment: try  json.dumps(all_data) before posting it.

Comment: its now saying 
    TypeError: <open file 'portports.txt', mode 'rb' at 0x7f4a3a2c1150> is not JSON serializable